# JQuery listening to form submit events

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've been pulling my hair out for the past couple hours, I can't seem to get a simple JQuery submit action listener to work. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<form id="hello-world" action="sayhello">
    <input type="submit" value="Hello!">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hello-world').submit(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
        alert("form submitted");
    });  
</script>
```

Upon clicking the "Hello!" button, no alert is displayed, and the action is preformed (ie my browser tries to load localhost/sayhello.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: so on the submission event you are trying to stop the submission. something about that seems fishy. try `click`.

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/GvJ4f/. You probably haven't included the jQuery library, check your console.

Comment: @user3237539 Thanks for that - turns out I was including JQuery after my javascript function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it might be something else, for example maybe jquery is not loading? are there any other errors in the console?

Your code works perfectly on jsfiddle without any changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/7jQRS/

```
<form id="hello-world" action="sayhello">
    <input type="submit" value="Hello!">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hello-world').submit(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
        alert("form submitted");
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - turns out I was having a senior moment, Jquery was only being included after my script...

Answer (score 0):

It might be trying to attach the event before the element is ready. Be sure to attached the handler after the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $('#hello-world').submit(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
        alert("form submitted");
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for the reply - turns out I was having a senior moment, Jquery was only being included after my script... I'll keep your tip about checking for Document.ready() in mind though!